# How to display dynamic name in google map waypoint API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-waypoints

Here i am doing Google map waypoint API, it is working fine.click the submit button then map will display in this map waypoint1 & waypoint 2 is comming static instedd of this i wantg to display empName (it is JSON response). i tried like i removed waypoint static values istead of this i given value.empNAme but this not working properly it showing last name only, how can do this.

```js
$('#btn-submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var res={
        "status": "success",
        "count": 3,
        "data":
            [
                {
                    "tripId": "1",
                    "pickUpLatitidute": "12.9565226",
                    "pickUpLongitude": "77.70730989999993",
                     "empName":"Arun",
                     "stratingTime" : "9.30 AM",
                      "presentStatus" : "Yes",
                },
                {
                    "tripId": "1",
                    "pickUpLatitidute": "12.9550587",
                    "pickUpLongitude": "77.68279819999998",
                    "empName":"Sharma",
                     "stratingTime" : "9.40 AM",
                      "presentStatus" : "Yes",
                },
                {
                    "tripId": "1",
                    "pickUpLatitidute": "12.9824",
                    "pickUpLongitude": "77.6927990",
                    "empName":"Dinesh",
                     "stratingTime" : "9.50 AM",
                     "presentStatus" : "Yes",
                }
            ]
        };


        
    if(res['status']=='success'){
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
        var waypts=[];
        $.each( res['data'], function( key, value ) {
           var map;
     var gmarkers = [];
     var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true
     });
     var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 14,
    center: {
      lat: 12.9577129,
      lng: 77.6764937
    } // Starting Point Marathahalli
     });
     directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

      //calculateAndDisplayRoute START HERE
     calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
             function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
              var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;
                 var latitdute = JSON.parse(value.pickUpLatitidute);
                 var longitude = JSON.parse(value.pickUpLongitude);
                 waypts.push(
                     {
                         location: {
                             lat: latitdute,
                             lng: longitude
                         },
                         stopover: true
                     }
                 );


                   directionsService.route({
      origin: {
        lat: 12.9577129,
        lng: 77.6764937
      }, // Must Need to give This is Starting Point.
      destination: {
        lat: 12.9868068,
        lng: 77.6070679
      }, // Must Need to give This is Ending Point.
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode],
      waypoints: waypts
       }, function(response, status) {
      if (status == 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        RenderCustomDirections(response, status);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
       });
             }
             //calculateAndDisplayRoute END HERE
             function RenderCustomDirections(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
     waypts = [];
     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
     var route = response.routes[0];
     startLocation = new Object();
     endLocation = new Object();

     var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
     var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
     
     for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
       if (i == 0) {
      startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
      startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
      startLocation.marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location, "start", legs[i].start_address, "green", String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0)));
       } else {
        
      waypts[i] = new Object();
      waypts[i].latlng = legs[i].start_location;
      waypts[i].address = legs[i].start_address;
      waypts[i].marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location, "waypoint" + i, legs[i].start_address, "yellow", String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + i));
      
       }
       endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
       endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
       var steps = legs[i].steps;
       for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
      var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
      for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
        bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
      }
       }
     }
     console.log(response);
     endLocation.marker = createMarker(endLocation.latlng, "My Company", endLocation.address, "red", String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + waypts.length));
     google.maps.event.trigger(endLocation.marker, 'click');
      } else alert(status);
    }
             var icons = new Array();
    icons["red"] = {
      url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png",
      // This marker is 32 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
      size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32),
      labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(16, 10)
    };

    function getMarkerImage(iconColor) {
      if ((typeof(iconColor) == "undefined") || (iconColor == null)) {
     iconColor = "red";
      }
      if (!icons[iconColor]) {
     icons[iconColor] = {
       url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/" + iconColor + ".png",
       // This marker is 32 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
       size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
       // The origin for this image is 0,0.
       origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
       // The anchor for this image is at 6,20.
       anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32),
       labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(16, 10)
     };
      }
      return icons[iconColor];

    }

    var iconImage = {
      url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png',
      // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
      size: new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(9, 34)
    };
    
    var iconShape = {
      coord: [9, 0, 6, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 0, 8, 0, 12, 1, 14, 2, 16, 5, 19, 7, 23, 8, 26, 9, 30, 9, 34, 11, 34, 11, 30, 12, 26, 13, 24, 14, 21, 16, 18, 18, 16, 20, 12, 20, 8, 18, 4, 16, 2, 15, 1, 13, 0],
      type: 'poly'
    };
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
    });

    function createMarker(latlng, title, html, color, label) {
      var contentString = '<b>' + title + '</b><br>' + html;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: latlng,
     draggable: true,
     map: map,
     icon: getMarkerImage(color),
     shape: iconShape,
     title: title,
     label: label,
     zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
      });
      marker.myname = title;
      gmarkers.push(marker);

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     infowindow.setContent(contentString);
     infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });

      return marker;
    }


        });
        console.log(waypts);
    }
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Travel modes in directions</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id="testForm">
  
 <select name="tripId">
  <option value="">Select trip</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>
 
 <button type="button" id="btn-submit">submit</button>
  </form><br></br>
  
    <div id="floating-panel">
    <b>Mode of Travel: </b>
    <select id="mode">
      <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
       <script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC7lDrYPDmJz1JsQh2rbWA9uRZHcFk_xJY">
    </script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> My JSON RESPONSE

```
var res={
    "status": "success",
    "count": 3,
    "data":
        [
            {
                "tripId": "1",
                "pickUpLatitidute": "12.9565226",
                "pickUpLongitude": "77.70730989999993",
                 "empName":"Arun",
                 "stratingTime" : "9.30 AM",
                  "presentStatus" : "Yes",
            },
            {
                "tripId": "1",
                "pickUpLatitidute": "12.9550587",
                "pickUpLongitude": "77.68279819999998",
                "empName":"Sharma",
                 "stratingTime" : "9.40 AM",
                  "presentStatus" : "Yes",
            },
            {
                "tripId": "1",
                "pickUpLatitidute": "12.9824",
                "pickUpLongitude": "77.6927990",
                "empName":"Dinesh",
                 "stratingTime" : "9.50 AM",
                 "presentStatus" : "Yes",
            }
        ]
    };
```

Comment: What text do you want to replace with `empName `? please clerify

Comment: If you click the marker in map, one dialouge box will open from there insteed of waypoint(static) ,  i want to give empName dyamically

Comment: Swamy m Check my answer

Comment: Please reserve the use of blockquote formatting (`>`) for quotations. Do not use it to "highlight" sections. You don't need formatting there at all; this should be set in plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `res.data[(i - 1)].empName` in the line below.

```
waypts[i].marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location, res.data[(i - 1)].empName, legs[i].start_address, "yellow", String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + i));
```

Working example below.

```js
$('#btn-submit').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var res = {
    "status": "success",
    "count": 3,
    "data": [{
        "tripId": "1",
        "pickUpLatitidute": "12.9565226",
        "pickUpLongitude": "77.70730989999993",
        "empName": "Arun",
        "stratingTime": "9.30 AM",
        "presentStatus": "Yes",
      },
      {
        "tripId": "1",
        "pickUpLatitidute": "12.9550587",
        "pickUpLongitude": "77.68279819999998",
        "empName": "Sharma",
        "stratingTime": "9.40 AM",
        "presentStatus": "Yes",
      },
      {
        "tripId": "1",
        "pickUpLatitidute": "12.9824",
        "pickUpLongitude": "77.6927990",
        "empName": "Dinesh",
        "stratingTime": "9.50 AM",
        "presentStatus": "Yes",
      }
    ]
  };


  if (res['status'] == 'success') {
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      var waypts = [];
      $.each(res['data'], function(key, value) {
        var map;
        var gmarkers = [];
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
          suppressMarkers: true
        });
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 14,
          center: {
            lat: 12.9577129,
            lng: 77.6764937
          } // Starting Point Marathahalli
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        //calculateAndDisplayRoute START HERE
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);

        function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
          var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;
          var latitdute = JSON.parse(value.pickUpLatitidute);
          var longitude = JSON.parse(value.pickUpLongitude);
          waypts.push({
            location: {
              lat: latitdute,
              lng: longitude
            },
            stopover: true
          });


          directionsService.route({
            origin: {
              lat: 12.9577129,
              lng: 77.6764937
            }, // Must Need to give This is Starting Point.
            destination: {
              lat: 12.9868068,
              lng: 77.6070679
            }, // Must Need to give This is Ending Point.
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode],
            waypoints: waypts
          }, function(response, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
              directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
              RenderCustomDirections(response, status);
            } else {
              window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
          });
        }
        //calculateAndDisplayRoute END HERE
        function RenderCustomDirections(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            waypts = [];
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var route = response.routes[0];
            startLocation = new Object();
            endLocation = new Object();

            var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
            var legs = response.routes[0].legs;

            for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
              if (i == 0) {
                startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
                startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
                startLocation.marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location, "start", legs[i].start_address, "green", String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0)));
              } else {

                waypts[i] = new Object();
                waypts[i].latlng = legs[i].start_location;
                waypts[i].address = legs[i].start_address;
                waypts[i].marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location, res.data[(i - 1)].empName + " " + res.data[(i -1)].stratingTime+  " " + res.data[(i -1)].presentStatus, legs[i].start_address, "yellow", String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + i));

              }
              endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
              endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
              var steps = legs[i].steps;
              for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
                var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
                for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
                  bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
                }
              }
            }
            endLocation.marker = createMarker(endLocation.latlng, "My Company", endLocation.address, "red", String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + waypts.length));
            google.maps.event.trigger(endLocation.marker, 'click');
          } else alert(status);
        }
        var icons = new Array();
        icons["red"] = {
          url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png",
          // This marker is 32 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
          size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
          // The origin for this image is 0,0.
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32),
          labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(16, 10)
        };

        function getMarkerImage(iconColor) {
          if ((typeof(iconColor) == "undefined") || (iconColor == null)) {
            iconColor = "red";
          }
          if (!icons[iconColor]) {
            icons[iconColor] = {
              url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/" + iconColor + ".png",
              // This marker is 32 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
              size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
              // The origin for this image is 0,0.
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              // The anchor for this image is at 6,20.
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32),
              labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(16, 10)
            };
          }
          return icons[iconColor];

        }

        var iconImage = {
          url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png',
          // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
          size: new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
          // The origin for this image is 0,0.
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(9, 34)
        };

        var iconShape = {
          coord: [9, 0, 6, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 0, 8, 0, 12, 1, 14, 2, 16, 5, 19, 7, 23, 8, 26, 9, 30, 9, 34, 11, 34, 11, 30, 12, 26, 13, 24, 14, 21, 16, 18, 18, 16, 20, 12, 20, 8, 18, 4, 16, 2, 15, 1, 13, 0],
          type: 'poly'
        };
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
        });

        function createMarker(latlng, title, html, color, label) {
          var contentString = '<b>' + title + '</b><br>' + html;
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            draggable: true,
            map: map,
            icon: getMarkerImage(color),
            shape: iconShape,
            title: title,
            label: label,
            zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
          });
          marker.myname = title;
          gmarkers.push(marker);

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(contentString);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          });

          return marker;
        }


      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Travel modes in directions</title>
  <style>
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
    
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #floating-panel {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      left: 25%;
      z-index: 5;
      background-color: #fff;
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #999;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
      line-height: 30px;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="testForm">

    <select name="tripId">
  <option value="">Select trip</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>

    <button type="button" id="btn-submit">submit</button>
  </form><br></br>

  <div id="floating-panel">
    <b>Mode of Travel: </b>
    <select id="mode">
      <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC7lDrYPDmJz1JsQh2rbWA9uRZHcFk_xJY">
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Its working but i want add more paramater value (stratingTime) , So tried like this but i am getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string .waypts[i].marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location, res.data[(i - 1)].empName, res.data[(i - 1)].stratingTime, legs[i].start_address, "yellow", String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + i));

Comment: Please see my JSON response i updated one more parameter called  stratingTime

Comment: @Mr Carsten Løvbo Andersen, i want add two more parameter in that dialogue box, like how we adding empName, please check my JSON Response i added two parameter called stratingTime & presentStatus, please update your answer

Comment: You should be able to add those "new" values the same way.  If this answered your original question, please [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), any new issues should result in a new question.

Comment: @Swamym You have nothing in your `res` that contains `stratingTime` Were should that come from

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen,are you there pls update your answer i facing lot issue for this, i am not able add those new stratingTime& presentStatus,can please reply me

Comment: @Swamym As i said in the comment before, Where should `stratingTime ` come from?

Comment: Please check my JSON response in top

Comment: @Swamym Check now, also if this is not how you want it, you have to tell me. Im not a mind reader

Comment: Mr@Carsten Løvbo Andersen, I Updated my JSON response separately also,got it ?

Comment: while click map marker ,How we are displaying in empName,same as i want to display this two fileds.

Comment: @Swamym Have you checked my new answer ?  or read my last comment.? Im getting a bit tired of that you think im a mind reader. Find a way to show me what it SHOULD look like